# Make groups by sessions in SAS EG

Tags: session, sas, enterprise-guide

I have a table in SAS EG that looks like this:

```
DateTime            User    Prod    Date        Date2       User2   Prod2   DateTime2           SecDiff Calc
20MAR2014:20:17:00  54823   1430    20140320    .           .       .       .                   .       1
13MAR2014:09:07:16  66019   8244    20140313    20140320    54823   1430    20Mar14:20:17:00    -644984 1
13MAR2014:09:07:44  66019   8244    20140313    20140313    66019   8244    13Mar14:09:07:16    28      0
13MAR2014:09:08:17  66019   8244    20140313    20140313    66019   8244    13Mar14:09:07:44    33      0
13MAR2014:09:08:43  66019   8244    20140313    20140313    66019   8244    13Mar14:09:08:17    26      0
13MAR2014:09:09:12  66019   8244    20140313    20140313    66019   8244    13Mar14:09:08:43    29      0
13MAR2014:09:10:34  66019   8244    20140313    20140313    66019   8244    13Mar14:09:09:12    82      0
13MAR2014:09:11:08  66019   8244    20140313    20140313    66019   8244    13Mar14:09:10:34    34      0
13MAR2014:09:11:34  66019   8244    20140313    20140313    66019   8244    13Mar14:09:11:08    26      0
14MAR2014:21:19:18  66019   8244    20140314    20140313    66019   8244    13Mar14:09:11:34    130064  1
14MAR2014:21:19:52  66019   8244    20140314    20140314    66019   8244    14Mar14:21:19:18    34      0
```

All the columns with a 2 is a lagged 1 version of the "non-2" columns.

This data illustrates a user activity on a specific product at a certain DateTime stamp.

I am interested in creating "Sessions" based on some parameters but is illustrated in the last column called "Calc". So for each new Session there should be a new number. The parameters are "Date=Date2", "User=User2", "Prod=Prod2", and "SecDiff<=3600".
The end goal is to calculate the Seconds of each sessions (by adding the SecDiff). 
So in this instance the table will be given me these results:

```
DateTime            User    Prod    Date        Seconds  Calc
20MAR2014:20:17:00  54823   1430    20140320    .        1
13MAR2014:09:07:16  66019   8244    20140313    258      2
14MAR2014:21:19:18  66019   8244    20140314    34       3
```

This returns the different in seconds, but removes the extreme value that is calculated and represents a new sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand this properly but why would you need all these columns. Just use first three like this

```
data a;
input act_time datetime20. product user;
cards;
20MAR2014:20:17:00  54823   1430    
13MAR2014:09:07:16  66019   8244    
13MAR2014:09:07:44  66019   8244 
13MAR2014:09:08:17  66019   8244
13MAR2014:09:08:43  66019   8244
13MAR2014:09:09:12  66019   8244 
13MAR2014:09:10:34  66019   8244   
13MAR2014:09:11:08  66019   8244   
13MAR2014:09:11:34  66019   8244    
14MAR2014:21:19:18  66019   8244
14MAR2014:21:19:52  66019   8244   
;
run;

proc sort data=a out=b; by product user act_time; run;

data c(drop=last_time);
retain last_time;
set b;
by product user;
if first.user then do; 
    session + 1;
    last_time = .;
end;
else do; 
    if act_time >= last_time + 3600 then do;
       session + 1;
    end;
end;
last_time = act_time;
run;    

data d;
retain first_time;
set c;
by session;
if first.session then do;
    first_time = act_time;
end;
if last.session then do;
    duration = act_time - first_time;
    output;
end;
run;
```